# Find and draw largest rect OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

I need to find the largest contour/rect on this image which should be the card.
[image: image description]

I try to use the following code but I get no drawing:

```
int largest_area=0;
int largest_contour_index=0;
cv::Rect bounding_rect;

Mat thr(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1);
Mat dst(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(0));
cvtColor(src,thr,CV_BGR2GRAY); //Convert to gray
threshold(thr, thr,25, 255,THRESH_BINARY); //Threshold the gray

vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours; // Vector for storing contour
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours( thr, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // Find the contours in the image

for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour.
{
    double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
    if(a>largest_area){
        largest_area=a;
        largest_contour_index=i;                //Store the index of largest contour
        bounding_rect=boundingRect(contours[i]); // Find the bounding rectangle for biggest contour
    }

}

Scalar color( 255,255,255);
drawContours( dst, contours,largest_contour_index, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy ); // Draw the largest contour using previously stored index.
rectangle(src, bounding_rect,  Scalar(0,255,0),1, 8,0);
```

Could someone provide me with an example using this image to find the largest rect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can try yourself by increasing the threshold.
2. Here You are finding biggest contour on thresholded image, so  display `thr` just after `threshold()` using  `imshow()`  and see what going on , and how it's look like.

See the result by increasing the threshold to little higher value.

```
threshold(thr, thr,100, 255,THRESH_BINARY); //Threshold the gray
```

**Threshold image**

[image]

Bounding rect for biggest contour

[image]